# DC gain from Nyquist Plot

Tags: control-system, gain

[image]

---

In the solution they have given like this

[image]

Here I did't get how they directly wrote DC gain 1?

---

I solved like this

\$GM=\frac{1}{\left |G(s)\right||H(s)|}\$
Here H(s)=1

From the plot GM=0.5

So G(s) will be 2 also System is type 2 so DC gain will be \$K_v=2\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a type 1 system, it follows that the steady-state error is \$0\$, from which it follows that the DC gain will be \$1\$.

As an example consider \$\frac{3}{s (s+1) (s+2)}\$, whose Nyquist plot is similar to the one you have. The closed-loop system is \$\frac{3}{s (s+1) (s+2)+3}\$. In the limit as \$s\$ approaches 0, it will be \$1\$.

More generally, consider a type 1 system \$\frac{k \ n(s)}{s \ d(s)}\$. The closed loop system is \$\frac{k \ n(s)}{s \ d(s)+k \ n(s)}\$. In the limit as \$s\$ approaches 0, it will simplify to \$\frac{k \ n(s)}{k \ n(s)}\$, which is \$1\$.

The system is type 1, because as \$\omega\$ decreases towards 0 the plot has goes to infinity almost along the imaginary axis. This is characteristic of a type 1 system.

Comment: Whats wrong in my method can you please tell?

Comment: also how they wrote its a unit step input without giving in the question. Please answer

Comment: First, it's not a type 2 system. If it was, the Nyquist plot will be along the real axis as \$\omega\$ decreases to zero. Second, the question has to do with dc gains, and you are computing gain margin and the static velocity error constant for some reason.

Comment: Look up the definition of dc gains (or steady-state gains). The input is assumed to be a unit step input.

Comment: Sorry I just saw its was typo I know its a type 1 system.because one 180 semicircle is there.

Comment: I did't get for the DC gain it will be unit step input part...Can you help me because i have to seach for that now

Comment: But I am confused now DC gain I always calculated for Open loop TF but you did it for Closed loop TF

Comment: The DC gain is simply the amount by which a DC signal will be amplified by the system. If you are still lost go through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFbUr5Vy_cc or something equivalent.

Comment: I will come back to you let me check my notes... I am a  bit comfused now

Comment: We are primarily interested in the closed-loop system. Nyquist plot is a tool that can tell you things about the closed-loop system based on the open-loop system.

Comment: Hii, in this question they have calculated steady state error...is that necessary? because without that you calculated DC gain.

Comment: It is not necessary. See the reasoning in paragraph 3 of my answer. However, you can also take the steady-state error route.

Comment: Sir can you please explain steady state error route in short please if you have time..or whenever you get time/

Comment: sir please have a look at this question too https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337093/find-the-largest-value-of-k-1-and-k-2-for-instability-of-the-system

Comment: What do you have trouble with when using the steady-state error. Do you want to know 1) how to get the steady state error, or 2)how it follows that the dc gain is 1 if the steady state error is zero.

Comment: the 2nd part sir

Comment: If the error is zero, what does it mean? It means that the measured output signal is identical to the reference signal. Their ratio is 1. That is, the dc gain is 1.