# Find the largest value of \$K_1\$ and \$K_2\$ for instability of the system

Tags: control, control-system

> A cascade control system with proportional controller is shown below

[image: schematic]

> Theroritically the largest values of the gain K1,and K2 that can be set withot causing instability of the closed loop sytem are
>
> Given \$G1=\frac{1}{(s+1)(2s+1)}\$ and \$G_2=\frac{1}{(3s+1)}\$
>
> \$(A)\$10 and 100 \$(B)\$100 AND 10 \$(C)\$10 AND 10\$(D)\$\$\infty\$ and \$\infty\$

---

The closed loop T.F will be

\$\frac{C(s)}{R(s)}=\frac{K_1K_2}{(s+1)(2s+1)(3s+1)+K_2(3s+1)+K_1K_2}\$

Now C.E will be 
$$6s^3+11s^2+(6+3K_2)s+1+K_2+K_1K_2=0$$

Now after applying **R.H criteria** I got two conditon for stability

that is $$20+9K_2-2K_1K_2>0$$ and $$1+K_2(1+K_1)>0$$

Now after satifying Options one by one all options becoming unstable for this equations.

Is the options are wrong or I am doing it wrong?

Comment: You have a typo. C.E must be \$6 s^3+\ldots\$.

Comment: @Suba Thomas sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing things right. I verified them using Mathematica. So either you have \$G_1\$ and \$G_2\$ wrong, or the question is wrong.

[image]

There are two possibilities:

1. The max value of \$K1\$ is \$\frac{9}{2}\$, and the max value of \$K2\$ is \$\infty\$.
2. \$K1\$ is some finite value greater than \$\frac{9}{2}\$, and \$0<\text{K2}<\frac{20}{2 \ \text{K1}-9}\$.

Comment: Thank you sir...Is there any alternate method to do this? and did you get the range with the software can't I do it manually?

Comment: Yes you can. If \$K1>0\$ and \$K2>0\$, the second condition is trivially satisfied. The first one can be written as \$20+K2(9-2 K1)>0\$. Now you have to consider two conditions \$(9-2 K1)>0\$ and \$(9-2 K1)<0\$, from which the two conditions follow. (You can also stop addressing me sir. :))